latexdiff \DIF commands near longtable captions cause "Misplaced" errors

Cross-posting from this GitHub issue.

I am running latexdiff on a document that needs to use the longtable package. If there are changes to the longtable's column alignment or to the caption, latexdiff will insert a \DIFaddend or a \DIFaddbegin on the same line as the \caption command and causes errors like:
\caption ->\noalign 
                    \bgroup \@ifnextchar [{\egroup \LT@c@ption \@firstofone ...
l.62 \DIFaddend \caption
                        {Table 1}\tabularnewline
I expect to see \noalign only after the \cr of
an alignment.

(and a similar error for "Misplaced \omit").
Here is a minimal example illustrating this issue:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs,array}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%DIF PREAMBLE EXTENSION ADDED BY LATEXDIFF
%DIF UNDERLINE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage[normalem]{ulem} %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage{color}\definecolor{BLACK}{rgb}{0,0,0}\definecolor{RED}{rgb}{1,0,0}\definecolor{BLUE}{rgb}{0,0,1} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddtex}[1]{{\protect\color{blue}\uline{#1}}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdeltex}[1]{{\protect\color{red}\sout{#1}}} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF SAFE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddbegin}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddend}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelbegin}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelend}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFmodbegin}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFmodend}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF FLOATSAFE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddFL}[1]{\DIFadd{#1}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelFL}[1]{\DIFdel{#1}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddbeginFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddendFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelbeginFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelendFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF HYPERREF PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFadd}[1]{\texorpdfstring{\DIFaddtex{#1}}{#1}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdel}[1]{\texorpdfstring{\DIFdeltex{#1}}{}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\newcommand{\DIFscaledelfig}{0.5}
%DIF HIGHLIGHTGRAPHICS PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage{settobox} %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage{letltxmacro} %DIF PREAMBLE
\newsavebox{\DIFdelgraphicsbox} %DIF PREAMBLE
\newlength{\DIFdelgraphicswidth} %DIF PREAMBLE
\newlength{\DIFdelgraphicsheight} %DIF PREAMBLE
% store original definition of \includegraphics %DIF PREAMBLE
\LetLtxMacro{\DIFOincludegraphics}{\includegraphics} %DIF PREAMBLE
\newcommand{\DIFaddincludegraphics}[2][]{{\color{blue}\fbox{\DIFOincludegraphics[#1]{#2}}}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\newcommand{\DIFdelincludegraphics}[2][]{% %DIF PREAMBLE
\sbox{\DIFdelgraphicsbox}{\DIFOincludegraphics[#1]{#2}}% %DIF PREAMBLE
\settoboxwidth{\DIFdelgraphicswidth}{\DIFdelgraphicsbox} %DIF PREAMBLE
\settoboxtotalheight{\DIFdelgraphicsheight}{\DIFdelgraphicsbox} %DIF PREAMBLE
\scalebox{\DIFscaledelfig}{% %DIF PREAMBLE
\parbox[b]{\DIFdelgraphicswidth}{\usebox{\DIFdelgraphicsbox}\\[-\baselineskip] \rule{\DIFdelgraphicswidth}{0em}}\llap{\resizebox{\DIFdelgraphicswidth}{\DIFdelgraphicsheight}{% %DIF PREAMBLE
\setlength{\unitlength}{\DIFdelgraphicswidth}% %DIF PREAMBLE
\begin{picture}(1,1)% %DIF PREAMBLE
\thicklines\linethickness{2pt} %DIF PREAMBLE
{\color[rgb]{1,0,0}\put(0,0){\framebox(1,1){}}}% %DIF PREAMBLE
{\color[rgb]{1,0,0}\put(0,0){\line( 1,1){1}}}% %DIF PREAMBLE
{\color[rgb]{1,0,0}\put(0,1){\line(1,-1){1}}}% %DIF PREAMBLE
\end{picture}% %DIF PREAMBLE
}\hspace*{3pt}}} %DIF PREAMBLE
} %DIF PREAMBLE
\LetLtxMacro{\DIFOaddbegin}{\DIFaddbegin} %DIF PREAMBLE
\LetLtxMacro{\DIFOaddend}{\DIFaddend} %DIF PREAMBLE
\LetLtxMacro{\DIFOdelbegin}{\DIFdelbegin} %DIF PREAMBLE
\LetLtxMacro{\DIFOdelend}{\DIFdelend} %DIF PREAMBLE
\DeclareRobustCommand{\DIFaddbegin}{\DIFOaddbegin \let\includegraphics\DIFaddincludegraphics} %DIF PREAMBLE
\DeclareRobustCommand{\DIFaddend}{\DIFOaddend \let\includegraphics\DIFOincludegraphics} %DIF PREAMBLE
\DeclareRobustCommand{\DIFdelbegin}{\DIFOdelbegin \let\includegraphics\DIFdelincludegraphics} %DIF PREAMBLE
\DeclareRobustCommand{\DIFdelend}{\DIFOaddend \let\includegraphics\DIFOincludegraphics} %DIF PREAMBLE
\LetLtxMacro{\DIFOaddbeginFL}{\DIFaddbeginFL} %DIF PREAMBLE
\LetLtxMacro{\DIFOaddendFL}{\DIFaddendFL} %DIF PREAMBLE
\LetLtxMacro{\DIFOdelbeginFL}{\DIFdelbeginFL} %DIF PREAMBLE
\LetLtxMacro{\DIFOdelendFL}{\DIFdelendFL} %DIF PREAMBLE
\DeclareRobustCommand{\DIFaddbeginFL}{\DIFOaddbeginFL \let\includegraphics\DIFaddincludegraphics} %DIF PREAMBLE
\DeclareRobustCommand{\DIFaddendFL}{\DIFOaddendFL \let\includegraphics\DIFOincludegraphics} %DIF PREAMBLE
\DeclareRobustCommand{\DIFdelbeginFL}{\DIFOdelbeginFL \let\includegraphics\DIFdelincludegraphics} %DIF PREAMBLE
\DeclareRobustCommand{\DIFdelendFL}{\DIFOaddendFL \let\includegraphics\DIFOincludegraphics} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF AMSMATHULEM PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\makeatletter %DIF PREAMBLE
\let\sout@orig\sout %DIF PREAMBLE
\renewcommand{\sout}[1]{\ifmmode\text{\sout@orig{\ensuremath{#1}}}\else\sout@orig{#1}\fi} %DIF PREAMBLE
\makeatother %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF COLORLISTINGS PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage{listings} %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage{color} %DIF PREAMBLE
\lstdefinelanguage{DIFcode}{ %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF DIFCODE_UNDERLINE %DIF PREAMBLE
  moredelim=[il][\color{red}\sout]{\%DIF\ <\ }, %DIF PREAMBLE
  moredelim=[il][\color{blue}\uwave]{\%DIF\ >\ } %DIF PREAMBLE
} %DIF PREAMBLE
\lstdefinestyle{DIFverbatimstyle}{ %DIF PREAMBLE
    language=DIFcode, %DIF PREAMBLE
    basicstyle=\ttfamily, %DIF PREAMBLE
    columns=fullflexible, %DIF PREAMBLE
    keepspaces=true %DIF PREAMBLE
} %DIF PREAMBLE
\lstnewenvironment{DIFverbatim}{\lstset{style=DIFverbatimstyle}}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\lstnewenvironment{DIFverbatim*}{\lstset{style=DIFverbatimstyle,showspaces=true}}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\lstset{extendedchars=\true,inputencoding=utf8}

%DIF END PREAMBLE EXTENSION ADDED BY LATEXDIFF

\begin{document}

\DIFdelbegin %DIFDELCMD < \begin{longtable}[c]{ p{2.5cm} p{1.5cm}}
%DIFDELCMD < %%%
\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \begin{longtable}[c]{ p{3cm} p{2cm}}
\DIFaddend \caption{Table 1}\tabularnewline
\toprule
Name & Value \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
Foo1 & Bar1 \\ \midrule
Foo2 & Bar2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}


\begin{longtable}[c]{ p{3cm} p{2cm}}
\DIFaddbegin \caption{\DIFadd{Table 2}}\DIFaddend\tabularnewline
\toprule
Name & Value \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
Foo1 & Bar1 \\ \midrule
Foo2 & Bar2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}


Is there something I can do in my preamble to avoid the clash between the \DIF commands and the \caption command?
If not, are there settings in latexdiff to simply ignore diffs related to the column alignment?
And, are there settings to add \DIFaddbegin before the longtable environment (instead of next to the \caption command)?


\caption is a \multicolumn in longtable, you can do \noalign{\DIFaddbegin} \caption but defining \DIFaddbegin to detect automatically that it needs that in this context might be a bit tricky

Not a real solution, but with --graphics-markup=NONE \DIFaddbegin and \DIFaddend turn into null commands in the standard markup style; then the longtable environment is no longer confused by the presence of these macros (as I did not have the input files, I could not test this completely, but I strongly believe this will work).
If you do want graphics mark-up another option is to use --add-to-config PICTUREENV=longtable  which will suppress all markup in longtable environments (again not fully tested).
